# does entity framework require a mapping for every model? I am creating my model and map by hand

Tags: entity-framework

when adding a view to my entity framework, is there such a thing as a model without a map?  How do I specify primary key property for a view in a map?

I am just trying to add a view to my entity framework so I can do a simple select from a table to populate a ddl.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve? some code snippets would be helpful too.

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461265/how-to-use-views-in-code-first-entity-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, but i don't think it hurts to add the model, so i did.