# How to create View (SQL) from Entity Framework in ABP Framework

Tags: entity-framework, view, aspnetboilerplate, sql-view

My situation is that I need to query from another database and show the result in my application. Both databases are on the same server. I came up with an idea on creating SQL-View in my database which would query the other database for values that I want. But I am not quite sure on how I can create or map SQL-View from the ABP framework?

I am using the full .Net framework with the Angular template.

Comment: Are you using code first approach?

Comment: yes I do. I think with ABP framework Code first is the only available option, isn't it?

Comment: Mention you EF and Project template version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating View is not directly supported in EF. So you can try the below approach.

- Create an empty Migration using `Add-Migration`.
- Write you Create View script in `Up` method of generated migration
  and run the script using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` method.
- Declare your class and use `Table` as you do for your model class.

`[Table("YourViewName")]`
`public class YourClassName`
`{`

`}`

- Ignore your view class like this
  `modelBuilder.Ignore<yourClassName>();` in `OnModelCreating` method.
- Run `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console.

Comment: thanks @vivek. would you please also explain what the step 4 does.

Comment: If you don’t do this, it will try to create table ‘YourViewName’. So by doing this step you are enforcing not to create table, instead you will create a view by using SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Create your table view in the database. Then using EF FluentAPI to config the view mapping. Here is the sample code:

**1. Create POCO class to map:**

```
 public class YourView
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
 }
```

**2. EF FluentAPI mapping configuration:**

Create map class:

```
 public class YourViewMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<YourView>
 {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<YourView> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("YourViewName");
        }
 }
```

Add mapping configuration to your DbContext (such as AbpCoreDbContext). Override OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new YourViewMap ());
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**3. Get data**:

using `IRepository<YourView>` to query data from the view.

P.S: related question [how to use views in code first entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461265/how-to-use-views-in-code-first-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `DbContext` for your legacy database. You can have multiple `DbContext` in an ABP application. Each `DbContext` have its own connection string. Creating view is kinda hackish.