# How to use a view that was added to the database after the init with EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The database I'm working with was built using EF Code First. My boss wrote a View for it that gets a particular set of data that the client needs, now I'm supposed to implement this View in the website.

I've never worked with views so my question is a simple one... How can I run this view using EF?

Comment: The same way as with the tables

Comment: @DmitryS that's all well and good but this database was built code first and the view added afterwards... I don't understand how to write a POCO in my model that'll give me what I need out of the view

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461265/how-to-use-views-in-code-first-entity-framework

Comment: Well... I'm still lost...

Comment: I can just advise you to create a new question with some more details about this new view. Perhaps someone can help you.